# getting the value of select tag inside a loop using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors

how can i get the value of a field inside a loop using jquery? 
ex.

```
<?php 
    for($counter=0; $counter<2; $counter++)
    {
       ?><select name="try<?php echo $counter; ?>">
       //bla bla bla..,.,.,.,.,. 
<?php 
    } 
 ?>
```

thankz a lot,.,.,

Comment: will you know the name ? .. $('input[name="try1]').val();

Comment: assuming that i do not know the length of the loop and i will get the value of the desired input,.,.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name=try]').val();
```

or if you need to know not the selected value, but value by index:

```
$('select[name=try]').find('option').eq(0).text(); - for text inside option node
$('select[name=try]').find('option').eq(0).attr('value') - for value attribute
```

where 0 is the index of the option node, i.e. 0 - first, 1 - second, etc.

You also have a counter after <select name="try0">, so naturally you would have to do $('select[name=try0]').val(), $('select[name=try1]').val(), etc

Comment: `$('select[name=try]').length === 0`

Comment: do i have to place the jquery code inside a loop also,.,.if,.,. yes then how do i do it?,.,.

Comment: no, i'd suggest to put jquery code anywhere outside the loop, otherwise you'll have as many javascript pieces as loops, which is dirty. Before the closing </body> tag, preferably.